# It is possible to detect a click on an ad loaded via iframe?

Tags: javascript

Having ads loaded via iframe, it is possible to detect a click with the left mouse button? A normal click?

I thought of another question, I saw a code that worked for me but it is not secure, since it monitors the activeElement, and has a flaw in it, if the user clicks with the right mouse button, the function triggers TRUE and triggers the alert.

[capture click on div surrounding an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690812/capture-click-on-div-surrounding-an-iframe)

Comment: not if the ad company is professional...

Answer (score 1):

If the advertisement is located on a different domain it is impossible because of security.

What you could attempt to do however, is to have a transparent element over the advertisement and detect the click there.

Then you would hide the element, and wait for the user to click a second time shrugging off the first click. If the user is actually interested in clicking the banner they will click a second time (when your transparent invisible element is gone).

### Update

Have a look at this: [HTML "overlay" which allows clicks to fall through to elements behind it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401658/html-overlay-which-allows-clicks-to-fall-through-to-elements-behind-it)

Apparently you can allow click through with `pointer-events` css.

Comment: I got to see a site using, but at the time I forgot to save the link it, it worked perfectly, used this same technique to create a transparent div.

Comment: Well, seems there is a workaround that I just posted. They even discuss a workaround for IE... you can have your click detection overlay and have the click go down :)