# Detect Click on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This has been answered in the context of "detect a click inside an iframe".

I don't need to know if a click is inside the iframe, but I'm trying to react to `swipe` events anywhere on the window for mobile browsers, and some embedded content is interfering with that.

I've tried attaching event handlers to `window` and `document`, with no success.

My suspicion is this isn't possible, but if is please let me know.

Comment: I've seen that, but it seems focused on the distinction of a click inside vs outside the iframe. I want to know if an event has happened, and don't need to distinguish it's origin.

Comment: Try overlaying a div over the iframe with `opacity: 0;`.

Comment: This might work, but in order to be clickable it would have to have a higher z-index than the iFrame, which seems like it would render the iFrame impossible to interact with.

Comment: this might seem completely crazy but if you can get the x,y,width,height position of the iframe and an x/y position of the mouse you can find out if the click occured inside the area of the iframe -with some basic maths. Now please feel free to insult my eagerness to sell a nuclear bomb when the customer only wanted some fireworks

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690896/1355315 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690990/1355315

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I think this question is not so much about figuring out _where_ the click happened, but _whether_ a click happened at all. If you look at abhitalks' first link, you'll see that's precisely the problem here.

Comment: @Wesley Yes, putting a div over it would render the iframe impossible to interact with (see the accepted answer in Neel's link).

Comment: @JLRishe I am getting confused, I though he wanted to register whether the user clicked within the iframe.

Comment: @Wesley maybe if you add some event where on document mousedown/touchstart, the overlay div is removed temporarily, you could still pass click events to the iframe. I haven't tested it though.