# Jquery function dont reconize the click on script

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

i need help with this script, it works when you click on the empty space, but when i click the script inside the div, the jquery function dont work, i need to make it work when i click on the script on the div get the div close by the cookie.

```
code in jsfiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FcFW2/406/

Comment: Which jQuery function?

Comment: when i click on the script inside the div this function dont work, only if i click outside of the script but in the div space  `$('#popupDiv').click(function() {
    $('#popupDiv').hide();
    createCookie('hide', true, 1)
    return false;  `

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag creates an iframe. Clicks in an iframe won't bubble up to the iframe's parent. You'd have to write the code in the iframe src link.

See [capture click on div surrounding an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690812/capture-click-on-div-surrounding-an-iframe) for a related question (your script tag basically inserts an iframe at the location)