# How to hide a parent element when click to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

Why I can't pass events from iframe to parent when are in different domains

```js
window.onload = function () {
    myFrame = document.getElementById('test2');
    myFrame.contentDocument.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        $("test1").hide();
    });
};
```

```html
<div id="test1" style="width:150px;height:150px;position:relative;">
    <iframe id="test2" src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

I want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nqTnz/15/

I try the same code with different domains and doesn't works: http://jsfiddle.net/z6tco5rg/

Comment: For [security reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289139/why-are-iframes-considered-dangerous-and-a-security-risk)

Comment: Same Origin Policy Restrictions prevents it

Comment: possible duplicate of [capture click on div surrounding an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690812/capture-click-on-div-surrounding-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if relevant, but have a read of this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585663/Communication-with-Cross-Domain-IFrame-A-Cross-Bro