# how to take innerHTML from one div to another with click

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, addeventlistener

I want to click a div or actually an iframe, and when i click the iframe i want to get the same content of that iframe to another iframe i got. I tried it like this but it will not work for me..

```
    var leser = document.getElementById("leser");
    var leser2 = document.getElementById("leser2");
    var leser1 = document.getElementById("leser1");

   leser.addEventListener("click", activateLeser);

      function activateLeser() {

      leser1.innerHTML = leser.innerHtmL;

    }
```

HTML code for the iframes:

```
  <div id="leser1">
<iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=good_deals&sort=n&app=433850_1"></iframe>
```

```
<div id="leser">
<iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_view_item&item=69274922&uid=76561198258576267"></iframe>
```

```
<div id="leser2">
<iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=%22Skin:%20All%20American%20Face%20Bandana%22"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you need to do `("click", activateLeser());` ?

Comment: javascript is case sensitive.  .innerHTML != .innerHtmL.

Comment: Maybe you aren't clicking or listening on the correct element? Try using `console.log()` on the value of `evt.target` and `evt.currentTarget`, where `evt` is the first parameter to the event listener function (which you need to define). Make sure they are what you expect.

Comment: i added the HTML code i have for the iframes now.

Comment: What i want is that when i click "leser" i want to make the "leser1" the same as "leser" (the one i click on)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
leser1.innerHTML = leser.innerHtmL;
```

to

```
leser1.src = leser.src;
```

The changed iframe will reload from scratch instead of copying the contents from the clicked one, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the div is the one calling the event, so clicking the Iframe wont register the event, since the Iframe content is from another page. I would recommend using a button, or allowing some space between the Iframe element and the Div but, if you are bent on doing it that way, try this

//add an Id to your iframe window

//add a click event to the Iframe window

iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener("click", function (event) {activateLeser(this.id); }, false);

it should work. Hope this helps

ps. Also chek out these questions on stack overflow. they are similar to yours
[Adding click event handler to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-click-event-handler-to-iframe)

[capture click on div surrounding an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690812/capture-click-on-div-surrounding-an-iframe)

Comment: can you explain alittle more on how i do it? Thank you!